# Rails: finding a record in an activerecord collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a product table and a set of variations for that product. 
I want to load in all the variations for a given product, then update individual records.

So say product X has 100 variations and I want to edit one of the variations. 
I query for all the variations that exist for the product.

```
vars = Variation.where(:product_id => 1) # => select * from variations
                                         #       where product_id = 1
```

select count = 1.
and I adjust the first record
update count = 1

Now I want to edit the record in this collection where the id = 10, but I don't want to go back to the database to pull down the record. 
Why should I?  I already have it in memory from the first select, right?

I might also like to read a bit of data from the record too.  Say the price of the variation.

I most definitely don't want to query the database for data I already have in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass criteria to `where`, you are telling ActiveRecord to build a query to retrieve only the matching records from the database, so when you ask for `Variation.where(:product_id => 1)` you have definitely not also loaded the one(s) into memory with product_id equal to 10.

If you really do want to load all of the records into memory, and then update them, then you should simply use `Variation.all`, and iterate over the results. Assuming you know there should only be one variation with any given product_id value, then you could also load them into a hash with product_ids as keys: `Hash[ Variation.all.map{|v| [v.id, v]} ]` .

Edit

This didn't perfectly address the original question, because I didn't get that by "id", Dave actually meant "id" and not "product_id". I'm glad the hash trick was still helpful in terms of an answer.

Comment: I already knew id=>10 was part of product 1, so I know it will be in the collection I got back. I was thinking of mapping the collection into a hash, and your little code was perfect.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question perfectly, but I'm glad my answer happened to include what you need :)

Comment: actually this was my code in the end..  variations.reduce({}) { |h, r| h[r.id] = r}

Comment: I actually added to_hash (withunderscore) as a monkey patch to activerecord::Relation.. i figured why not... all my tables have id's.

Answer (score 3):

The result set implements enumerable, so you can do fun stuff like this:

```
my_collection = vars.find_all { |var| var.product_id == 10 }
```

Which will yield a subset as an array that you can proceed to do whatever you want with.

Comment: I believe a collection is really just an array.

Comment: Oh.. Now I see what you did.. very clever. I'll have to put that little bit in my head.. I went with the hash, but this too is quite smart.

Comment: Thanks! Enumerable is a pretty rad mixin that a lot of collection objects use, and it has tons of utility http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html